# check whether an array contains an index or not php

Tags: php, array-key-exists

This is my post data from front end.

```
{"camp": 1, "seg": [{"id":15 "rule":[{"id":152},{"id":153, "NAME":"file2"}]},
{"id":16,  "rule":[{"id":152, "NAME":"null"}]}
]}
```

What I need is I do want to check inside the RULE array that It contains an index called NAME or not. if I check like the below code

```
foreach ($segment as $segementkey => $segmentdata) {
    foreach($segmentdata['rule'] as $rulekey => $ruledata){
        if ( array_key_exists ($ruledata['NAME'], $ruledata)) {
            $is_new = true;     
            $this->logger->debug('name');
        }
        else
            $this->logger->debug('nooo name');
    }
}
```

I got the error as undefined index NAME. So what is the way to check that the index or element of an array present or not? Thanks in advance

Comment: First **decode** the `json` and then check. It should be `NAME` not `name` in `if` condition.

Comment: even if I change like that also getting same error. Now I have edited my post with the correction

Comment: `NAME` is in capital. You have written like, `Name`.

Comment: You are using `array_key_exists()` wrong, you need `array_key_exists('NAME', $ruledata)`.

Comment: Seems like your json is not valid. You are missing a `,` between id and rule under `seg` key. check it.

Comment: @YashParekh Probably a typo copying the question here; if the code gets into the loop, the json has been decoded successfully.

Comment: Thanks @jeron. I do have to check as array_key_exists('NAME', $ruledata)

Comment: @jeroen sounds correct.